# Bootstrap DropDown menu large left margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/large-dropdown-menu

I would like to have the menu aligned with each menu item.
I don't want that the menu starts on the left:0 on the all items.

I have already achived this with the classic dropdown menù.

Do you think is possible with no hacks and pure bootstrap and **large menu dropdown**?

Let me know, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, but on the last items you will have some issues:

http://jsbin.com/nehafi/

```
.dropdown-menu-large {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  left:auto; /* added */
}
```

You might want to check out http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/ - which gives you about 10 lines max of css to do a lot more with the menu position.

Comment: Wow, almost working.   There is a problem on the last menu items: 
http://cl.ly/image/040a1b0F462v

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, use Yamm3 (see question) and do the full width thing or you can add different class to those last items and adjust position.

Comment: Link to Yamm3 question?

Comment: Add `.col-sm-3 { min-width:100px;}` to resolve the issue of the last menu item. http://jsbin.com/dicemikuzi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yes, but when the viewport changes size that column gets very narrow. Unless the OP wants to right some jQuery to detect edge and so forth, the best bet is to do a full-width which is an option with the Yamm3 menu plugin css, it also looks better.